# PHP REST API 404

Tags: php, json

I am doing it for the first time API in Php. It finds one product by id. If there is a product in the database -> code 200 if it is not -> code 404. But 404 not working.

What am I doing wrong?

**1. code 200** it works 
Output:

```
/get_id2.php?id=39

records 0   
id  "39"
caption     "Product1"
filename    "Image01.jpg"
```

**2. code 404** did not work
Output:

```
/get_id2.php?id=39999 (there is no product)

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data
```

**Code:**

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

include_once('config_setup.php');

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * ";
$sql .= "FROM photographs ";
$sql .= "WHERE id='" . db_escape($db, $id) . "'";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
confirm_db_connect($result);

// products array
$products_arr=array();
$products_arr["records"]=array();
$message = [];


      while($photo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

      if($photo['caption']!=null){  

      extract($photo); 

            $product_item = array(

            "id"            => $id,
            "caption"       => $caption,
            "filename"      => $filename,

        );
          // set response code - 200 OK
          http_response_code(200);
          array_push($products_arr["records"], $product_item);
          echo(json_encode($products_arr));

      } else {
          // set response code - 404 Not found
          http_response_code(404);
         // tell the user product does not exist
         echo json_encode(array("message" => "Product does not exist."));
      }   
 } 

mysqli_free_result($result);

db_disconnect($db);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before `mysqli_fetch_assoc` you check if the result is **true** or **false**. In case of no records, `mysqli_query` returns a **boolean false**.

You could have something like :

```
    if(!$result) {
              http_response_code(404);
              //response message
        }
        else {
              //process result 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and prompt, If you want, see my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works now. I solved the problem:)

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    include_once('config_setup.php');

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * ";
    $sql .= "FROM photographs ";
    $sql .= "WHERE id='" . db_escape( $db, $id ) . "'";

    $result = mysqli_query( $db, $sql );
    confirm_db_connect( $result );

    $photo = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result );

    $id = $photo['id'];
    $caption = $photo['caption'];
    $filename = $photo['filename'];

    if ($photo['caption'] != null) {

        // create array
        $product_arr = array(
            "id" => $photo['id'],
            "caption" => $photo['caption'],
            "filename" => $photo['filename']
        );


        // set response code - 200 OK
        http_response_code(200);
        echo json_encode( $product_arr );

    } else {
        // set response code - 404 Not found
        http_response_code(404);
        // tell the user product does not exist
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Product does not exist."));
    }

    mysqli_free_result( $result );

    db_disconnect( $db );
```